# History command does not work when HISTFILE variable is set

Tags: linux, bash

We have a common Linux test env where multiple people work(connect through ssh using Putty),
We have a requirement to store commands fired from all terminals in such a way that we can track each and every command, fired by which IP/user and from which TTY so that we can verify it using 'last' command.

I have changed my .bash_profile accordingly

```
# Will Give me ip of person logged in
WHOAMI=`who -m | cut -d '(' -f 2| cut -d ')' -f1`  
# Will give me tty ID
MYTTY=`who -m | awk '{print $2;}' | cut -d '/' -f2`
DATE=`date +"%Y_%m_%d_%H%M%S"`
DAY=`date +"%Y_%m_%d"`
shopt -s histappend
mkdir -p $HOME/HISTORY/${WHOAMI}/${DAY}
touch $HOME/HISTORY/${WHOAMI}/${DAY}/.HIST_${MYTTY}_${DATE}
export HISTTIMEFORMAT='%F %T '
export HISTFILESIZE=100
export HISTSIZE=100
# stores history file per terminal
export HISTFILE=$HOME/HISTORY/${WHOAMI}/${DAY}/.HIST_${MYTTY}_${DATE}
export PS1='[\[\e[4;32m\]\u@\h\[\e[0m\] \[\e[1;36m\]$PWD\[\e[0m\]]\! $'
# Updates the HISTFILE at real time i.e. when user presses enter
export PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a; history -c; history -r; ${PROMPT_COMMAND}"
history -r $HISTFILE
```

After changing the `.bash_profile`, the `history` command stopped showing previous entries.

When I changed `PROMPT_COMMAND` to `"history -a; history -r; ${PROMPT_COMMAND}"` it started working but

1. The `HISTFILE` is not updated at real time; it's only updated when exit command is fired.
2. If user disconnects the putty session by right click and using disconnect option, `HISTFILE` is not updated at all. :(

P.S:- If i comment `export HISTFILE` it stores to `.bash_history` file and everything works smoothly and `.bash_history` is updated in real time, but I do not get the tty id or IP from which command was fired

O.S:- Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.8 (Santiago)

Comment: In the future, please indent your code by four spaces in order to create correct formatting (or use the `{}` icon on the formatting bar). And please avoid excessive vertical whitespace (i.e. blank lines); we're used to reading code line by line. @pcnate: When editing, be aware that people sometimes insert backslashes to avoid special handling of certain formatting characters, and that these must be removed when you fix the formatting. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, It was my first post so was unaware of this, sorry for that, in future will it keep in mind.

Answer (score 3):

Replacing

```
touch $HOME/HISTORY/${WHOAMI}/${DAY}/.HIST_${MYTTY}_${DATE}
```

with

```
printf "#`date '+%s'`\nll\n" > $HOME/HISTORY/${WHOAMI}/${DAY}/.HIST_${MYTTY}_${DATE}
```

Did the trick, so it seems that only if there is some data in HISTFILE file, history command updates it properly at real time else it updates it only when exit command is fired.

Comment: great!.. I was struggling this for a longtime and your post helped me..

Comment: the `ll` line written by `printf "#\`date '+%s'\`\nll\n"` would break my history. but it perfectly works without the additional `ll`.